Separable Hilbert spaces, total orthonormal sets and Schauder basis in Banach spaces
A Schauder basis for a Banach space $X$ is called the sequece $\{e_n\}$ where $x\in X$ can be expanded as:
$$x=\sum^\infty_{k=1} a_ke_k$$
A total orthonormal basis in a Hilbert space $H$ is a Schauder basis $\{e_n\}$ where $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}$.
The textbook I'm studying from, "Kreyszig - Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications", on p.69 says:
$$$$ "Conversely, does every separable Banach space have a
Schauder basis? This is a famous question raised by Banach himself
about forty years ago. Almost all known separable Banach spaces had
been shown to possess a Schauder basis. Nevertheless, the surprising
answer to the question is no." $$$$
However on p.168 when explaining how every Hilbert space contains a total orthonormal set it says:
$$$$
"For an infinite dimensional
separable H it follows from the Gram-Schmidt process by
(ordinary) induction."
$$$$
My question is: How exactly can you construct such a total orthonormal set in separable $H$ where it won't work for separable $X$? Also why can't we just take the dense countable set $\{x_i\}\in X$ and $\{h_i\}\in H$ and exclude the linearly dependent vectors from it after which just use the Gram-Schmidt process (for the Hilbert space)? This can't be valid since not all separable Banach spaces can have a Schauder basis.

This is a reasonable question - and it demonstrates how special Hilbert space structures are. Indeed, the point here is that for a Hilbert space, applying Gram-Schmidt to a countable dense sequence yields an orthonormal sequence $\{e_n\}$ whose span is dense. But an orthonormal sequence whose span is dense is necessarily a Schauder basis and thus an orthonormal basis. This is because, once you have such an orthonormal sequence, the map $l^2 \to H$, $(a_n) \mapsto \sum_n a_ne_n$ is an isometry. Whence, its range is closed. Clearly, the range contains the span of $\{e_n\}$, so it must be the entirety of $H$. That is, every element of $H$ can be written uniquely as an infinite linear combination of $\{e_n\}$, so it is an orthonormal basis.
The same, however, does not work for a general separable Banach space. Of course, there’s no inner product to begin with, so you can’t talk about orthogonality. The most that can be done is a linearly independent $\{x_n\}$ whose span is dense (you can also assume they all have norm $1$, but for the purpose of getting a Schauder basis, normalization is irrelevant). But such a sequence needs not be a Schauder basis. In fact, both the existence (every element can be written as an infinite linear combination) and the uniqueness (the coefficients of the said infinite linear combination are unique) may not hold:

By Stone-Weierstrass, polynomials are dense in $C[0, 1]$. So $\{x^n\}_{n \geq 0}$ is a linearly independent sequence whose span is dense. But the only functions that can be written as an infinite linear combination of $\{x^n\}$ are analytic functions, whereas there are continuous functions that are not analytic.
In $l^2$, you can consider $\{\sum_n \frac{1}{n}e_n\} \cup \{e_n\}_n$. This is a linearly independent sequence whose span is dense, and in fact any element of $l^2$ can be written as an infinite linear combination of them - but not uniquely. Say, $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}e_n$ can clearly be written in two different ways.

